How to create a pre-cancelled CancellationToken efficiently?
I have a rare scenario (in unit tests) that needs to generate a CancellationToken that is already cancelled , I can certainly do
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.Cancel();

Send(cts.Token);

we know that we have CancellationToken.None for non-cancellable request purpose, but do we have a counterpart, something like CancellationToken.Cancelled we can use out of box so that I don't need to create a CancellationTokenSource in the first place then cancel it?

You're welcome to cache one yourself. You already recognise that this is a niche usage, why should that be overly optimized?

You can just use new CancellationToken(true). See this.

According to the CancellationToken docs here you can simply pass in a boolean to define the cancelled state of the token when generating it
